# When updating python3 using homebrew I get an error saying "python3 not installed"

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I Ran `$brew upgrade python3` and got an error saying `python3 not installed` although it is installed and running `$python3 --version` outputs the version number which is 3.7.0

Comment: Can you post the output of `brew upgrade python3 --verbose` and `brew info python3` please? Are you sure `python3` has been installed with Homebrew?

Comment: It turns out I had installed it from python.org and not from homebrew. so I updated it by downloading the latest version. thanks for pointing that out